# Equivalent to clojure.contrib's show?

Tags: clojure, clojure-contrib

There used to be this [useful utility called show](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.repl-utils/show) in clojure.contrib. Now, that it's deprecated, is there an equivalent to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

De-constructing `show` to be more "simple", making available distinct pieces of re-usable functionality, was discussed by Stuart Halloway in a [talk](https://github.com/downloads/stuarthalloway/clojure-presentations/Clojure-Simplicity.pdf) he give on clojure simplicity.

The resulting code makes use of `clojure.reflect/reflect` and `clojure.pprint/print-table`
and standard clojure `filter`:

```
(require 'clojure.reflect)
(require 'clojure.pprint)

(->> (clojure.reflect/reflect java.lang.String)
     :members
     (filter #(.startsWith (str (:name %)) "last"))
     (clojure.pprint/print-table))
```

Comment: One of the cool things about `show` is that it worked on instances as well as on types (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821286). Are you aware of any examples (e.g. in Clojuredocs or blogs) that show how to pprint the values of instance variables of an instance of a Java class? The clojure.repl namespace doesn't seem to have enough (https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.repl-api.html)

Comment: clojure.reflect/reflect above is built on top of the Java reflection API so it should do what you need.  Part of the point of breaking apart "show" was it was doing too much. The reflect functionality was made available in the clojure.reflect namespace (rather than the repl-api).  Try the above example with a string instance instead of the type - (clojure.reflect/reflect "instance of a string")

Answer (score 6):

I refer you to the [Where Did Clojure.Contrib Go](http://dev.clojure.org/display/community/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go) document, which says about clojure.contrib.repl-utils:

> Migrated to clojure.repl and clojure.java.javadoc.  show functionality similar to clojure.reflect/reflect.

The clojure.reflect API documentation is [here](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.reflect-api.html), and the clojuredocs.org examples are [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.reflect/reflect).